# From discrete equation to ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

I was wondering in how to convert a moving average of the form:

$$x_t=\alpha x_{t-1} + (1-\alpha)y_t$$

into an ODE. I thought I could do something like:

$$x_t-x_{t-1} = (\alpha-1)(x_t-y_t)$$

and then divide by $\Delta_t$ to take limits. But this does not seem to help as it results on an unwanted $\Delta_t$ on the rhs before taking the limit ($\Delta_t \rightarrow 0$) to convert the lfh into a derivative.

Comment: Put  $\beta=\frac{(\alpha-1)}{\Delta_t}$